# reactJS SCSS background-image not visible

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, background

I'm working on react and I want to use a local image in a public folder as a background with Transparent color as div container.
the problem is this image not showing at all

my method work with a different image from the internet (that start with https)
I also tried to put it in CSS but still the same thing

this is code of background from local image (not visible )
`background-image: url("/public/images/background.jpg");`

also, tried this

`background: #eaeaea urlurl("/public/images/background.jpg");`

this is the code of background from the internet (visible )
    
`background: #eaeaea url("https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/full page/img(20).jpg");`

**I think my problem with this methude url('/path/path/img.jpe) it shuld be **

````
// Import Bootstrap and its default variables
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';

.btn{
    color: red;
}

.background {
    background: #eaeaea url("/public/images/background.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }```
````

Comment: Do you a link to the working code?

Comment: sorry ,I don't get it 
but I feel that I should call the image without URL like I should call it with src

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this :

```
background: url('/./images/background.jpg');
```

Maybe it will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to create an .env file in your project
Directory and Insert this code: `SASS_PATH=node_modules:src` then copy all the images
you want to use in **src** folder.

```
background-image: url("/background.jpg");
```

Answer (score -3):

I believe you just need to add image to your background tag i.e:

```
background-image: url("/public/images/background.jpg");
```